# Select 2 not populated with ajax and pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

i want populate the select 2 control with active directory users account, for inserting them to database, but even i see a json results in response by using F12 the select 2 is not populating

the used select2 referenced in Shared/layout view

there is by controller Action method

```
public JsonResult GetUsersFiltredPaged(string match, int page = 1, int pageSize = 5)
    {
        PrincipalContext contextPrincipal = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(contextPrincipal);
        PrincipalSearcher searchPrincipal = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal);
        var totalCount = searchPrincipal.FindAll().Count();
        List<UserPrincipal> usersAD = new List<UserPrincipal>();

        foreach (UserPrincipal users in searchPrincipal.FindAll())
        {
            if (users.EmployeeId != null)//prendre les comptes qui ayant un matricule paie
            {
                UserPrincipal userAd = users;
                userAd.DisplayName = users.DisplayName + '(' + users.EmailAddress + ')';
                userAd.EmployeeId = users.EmployeeId;
                usersAD.Add(userAd);
            }
        }
        IEnumerable<ModelDto> model = (from u in usersAD.AsQueryable().OrderBy(i=>i.DisplayName).Skip(page*(pageSize-1))
                                            .Take(pageSize)
                                select new ModelDto{id= u.EmployeeId, text=u.DisplayName});
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(match))
        {
            model = model.Where(i => i.text.Contains(match));
        }


            ResultList<ModelDto> results = new ResultList<ModelDto> { items = model.ToList(), totalCount = usersAD.Count };
            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);



    }
```

my drop down list razor

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterModify", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal"}))
     {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

       <div class="well blanc" >

          <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedMatric, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMatric, Model.DisplayedNames, "--Selectionnez--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedMatric, new { id="SelectedMatric"})*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedMatric, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

  @*the rest of view *@
  <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Créer" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </p>
```

the java script code

```
  $('#SelectedMatric').select2({
            placeholder: "--Selectionnez--",
            width: '100%',
            minimumInputLength: 0,
            allowClear: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUsersFiltredPaged")',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'Get',

                data: function (term, page) {
                    return { match: term, page: page, pageSize: 5 };
                },
                results: function (result, page) {
                    var more = (page * 5) < result.totalCount;
                    return { results: result.items, page: page, more: more };
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with that:[in forum.asp.net](https://forums.asp.net/t/2160647.aspx?Select%202%20not%20populated%20with%20ajax)

model

```
public class ModelDto
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class ResultList<T>
{
    public List<T> items { get; set; }
    public int total_count { get; set; }
}
```

view

```
ipt>

    $(function () {
        $('#SelectedMatric').select2({
            placeholder: "--Selectionnez--",
            width: '50%',
            minimumInputLength: 0,
            allowClear: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUsersFiltredPaged")',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'Get',

                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        match: params.term,
                        page: params.page || 1,
                        pageSize: params.pageSize || 5
                    }
                    return query;
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    console.log(params);
                    return {
                        results: data.items,
                        page:params.page,
                        pagination: {
                            more:(params.page * 5) < data.total_count
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        });
    })

</script>
```

controller:

```
public JsonResult GetUsersFiltredPaged(string match, int page = 1, int pageSize = 5)
    {
        List<ModelDto> model = new List<ModelDto>
        {
            new ModelDto{id = "1", text  = "Option1" },
            new ModelDto{id = "2", text  = "Option2" },
            new ModelDto{id = "3", text  = "Option3" },
            new ModelDto{id = "4", text  = "Option4" },
            new ModelDto{id = "5", text  = "Option5" },
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(match))
        {
            model = model.Where(m => m.text.Contains(match)).ToList();
        }

        ResultList<ModelDto> results = new ResultList<ModelDto>
        {
            items = model,
            total_count = 5,
        };
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```